# Pydev output in Eclipse console truncated by triple period

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, debugging, server, pydev

My favourite thing about Eclipse and Pydev is using the remote debugging feature. This is of great help when debugging python modules in other applications.

However, despite setting the console to unlimited output, (right click on console > preferences > **Limit Console output**) I still find that stdout being routed to my debug server is **truncated** when printed to my console. For example : (traceback shortened to give my fingers break)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "blah/blah/blah.py", line
 113, in solve
     solver(thing[i]) TypeError: 'f...
```

And that's it. It ends with a ... without printing the whole darn thing. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually done by the debugger backend itself. There's a constant (MAX_IO_MSG_SIZE) which limits it at org.python.pydev_xxx/pysrc/pydevd_comm.py

So, if you want, you can raise that value to a bigger value (default is 1000 chars/message). There's currently no way to customize that value from the UI (maybe it could be set initially by some environment variable -- such as PYDEVD_MAX_IO_MSG_SIZE -- if it's available... care to submit a patch? See: http://www.pydev.org/developers.html for getting the code).

Comment: Thank you! I haven't had time to examine this closely but I'm sure you are correct.

Comment: Ah, so I have confirmed this by copying pydevd to my home folder, modifying the module as you have described. And SUCCESS, I get full stdout and stderr back now, which is fantastic as I tend to interact alot with the remote debugger. Thank you!